# How to add NT AUTHORITY\IUSR to Administrators group

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, directoryentry

I want to add the IUSR account to that administrators group in my winforms application. The code below fails because it cant find a user for "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR":

```
 DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
 DirectoryEntry administrators = AD.Children.Find("Administrators", "group");
 DirectoryEntry iusr = AD.Children.Find(@"NT AUTHORITY\IUSR", "user");

 administrators.Invoke("Add", new object[] {iusr.Path.ToString()});
```

I realize this is a bad idea. I am doing this because I am writing a winforms application that programmatically creates a new website in IIS7 FOR DEVELOPMENT PURPOSES ONLY. The website is being created successfully however ASP.NET displays the error "Access is denied" whenever I try to load a page. When I add IUSR to the administrators group everything works fine. What else can I try? Below is the code I am using to create the new website:

```
Site site = servermgr.Sites.Add(websitename, physicalpath, port);
Binding binding = site.Bindings.CreateElement();
string bindinginfo = "*:" + port.ToString() + ":" + hostipaddress;

binding.Protocol = "http";
binding.BindingInformation = bindinginfo;
site.Bindings.Clear();
site.Bindings.Add(binding);

site.Applications.Add(applicationpath, applicationphysicalpath);

site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = "Default";

servermgr.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: you can't add a non-existant user... what is your question exactly ?

Comment: This is a ***bad*** idea

Comment: @Yahia IUSR is a valid built-in security principal

Comment: @Neil yes, but at least on the machines I saw it just start with IUSR PLUS some additional charachters!

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but whatever it is this must be an extremely *dangerous* way of doing it. Allowing anonymous requests to have full administrator privileges is a recipe for total disaster.

Comment: Additional characters: should be underscore followed by machine name

Comment: You could try to impersonate an domain user with proper (and restricted) privileges, or define an application pool with a less privileged user

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is to require authentication for the page. This then prompts the browser for you to log on; if you use a suitably empowered account the page will then be able to create the new website.

IIS7 allows you to configure this from (e.g.) ApplicationHost.config while previous versions required you to edit the metabase (usually from IIS manager).

EDIT: Depending on authentication, browser and network configuration, it is possible to arrange for the browser to automatically log in to the page using your domain account.

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
DirectoryEntry administrators = AD.Children.Find("Administrators", "group");

administrators.Invoke("Add", new object[] {"WinNT://NT AUTHORITY/IUSR"});
```